# Setting jQuery validation messages option to another map

Tags: jquery, validation, message

I've got the rules defined below for a page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.validator.setDefaults({ 
    submitHandler : function() { alert("submitted!"); }
});

$("#prospectForm").validate({
    errorLabelContainer : $("#errorDiv ul"),
    wrapper : "li",
    debug : true,
    rules : {
        prospectName : {
            required : true,
            rangelength : [2, 45]
        },
        groupSize : {
            required : true,
            digits : true
        },
        zipCode : {
            required : true,
            digits : true,
            rangelength : [5, 5]    
        },
        sicCode : {
            required : true,
            rangelength : [4, 4],
            digits : true
        },
        agencyProducer : {
            required : true 
        }
    },
            messages : errorMap
}); 
});
```

I defined errorMap like the following:

```
var errorMap = {
prospectName : {
    required : "An entry is required in field Prospect.",
    rangelength : "Prospect Name must be between 2 and 45 characters."
},
groupSize : {
    required : "An entry is required in field Group Size.",
    digits : "Numeric data is required in field Group Size."
},
zipCode : {
    required : "An entry is required in field Zip Code.",
    digits : "Numeric data is required in field Zip Code.",
    rangelength : "Zip Code must be 5 digits."
}, 
sicCode : {
    required : "This is an invalid SIC code. Enter the SIC again or search for the SIC code.",
    rangelength : "This is an invalid SIC code. Enter the SIC again or search for the SIC code.",
    digits : "This is an invalid SIC code. Enter the SIC again or search for the SIC code."
}, 
agencyProducer : {
    required : "An entry is required in the Agent field."
}   
};
```

When I run this, I get errorMap undefined.  I am including the errorMap definition code in a separate .js file and including this errorMsgDefs.js inside the html file after I include the jQuery and jQuery.validate files.

Any ideas?  The docs say you can use a map for the value of the messages option, so what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it sounds to me like its either not loading or its out of scope try making it global by remove the "var" before errorMap = and see if that fixes the problem

Comment: It turns out the .js file was corrupt somehow.  I deleted and created new file and it worked fine.  Thanks.

Comment: sorry I couldn't be more helpful but glad you got it figured out